# How a good idea to deal with very large request in .NET Core 3.1 and Entify Framework Core

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, .net-core, task

I want to send a remove request from Angular, but the request needs to check a lot of tables in the database. The task takes a very long time to complete, how can I deal with this scenario?

I don't want the front end to wait for a response, I want to process the task in the background and send a message to the frontend when the task finishes.

Using Task without wait is a good I deal?

Comment: This type of question would be better served on a different StackExchange community like Software Engineering. StackOverflow is geared towards specific programming problem Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using Task without wait is a good idea?
```

No. Asynchronous web requests are geared towards allowing a web server to free up response threads, *not* attempting to make web requests themselves faster.

Faced with a requirement to capture a request from a client and process it in the background without the client expecting/waiting for a result, I would consider employing a queuing mechanism. The API web request accepts the data and pushes the request details into a processing queue. A background Windows service can pop messages off the queue, process the requests against data using EF, and handle any exceptions etc.

The main considerations for employing a queue for long running operations is that it can help contain concurrent requests. If a single operation takes 30+ seconds to complete and cause a number of locks on the database and is triggered by an API call, what will happen when your web server receives 100 such requests within a few minutes? If the web server were to just spawn off background threads/tasks, these would quickly start deadlocking each other and other requests attempting to access the database. By employing a queue, you can throttle how many of these requests are processed at any one time. 100 requests may be queued up, but the processing service can ensure that only one or a handful are processing at any one time.

Queuing can be facilitated by a number of persistence-enabled libraries like MSMQ or can be managed entirely with a database table or tables. Write the request fields as a record with a created timestamp, isProcessing, and/or result column. The service polls to pick up one or more rows in the order they were added, marks them as processing, then updates the result or deletes the row when completed.